# express is not recognized in cmd in windows 7

Tags: node.js, express, installation, npm

js on my windows 7 machine, i have executed the below commands from

C:\node> npm install -g express -generator

and also C:\node> npm install -g express -generator@4, and also the npm link express

for the above commands, i got the below messages.

```
express@4.10.7 C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
├── methods@1.1.1
├── finalhandler@0.3.3
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── serve-static@1.7.2
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── vary@1.0.0
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@1.0.0
├── qs@2.3.3
├── on-finished@2.2.0 (ee-first@1.1.0)
├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
├── debug@2.1.1 (ms@0.6.2)
├── type-is@1.5.5 (mime-types@2.0.7)
├── accepts@1.1.4 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.7)
├── send@0.10.1 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11, on-finished@2.1.1)
└── proxy-addr@1.0.4 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.5)
```

and with npm link express:

C:\node\node_modules\express -> C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\express

but still when i execute the express nodetest1 at C:/node> i am getting the express is not recognized error.

anyone know any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `express` and `-generator` above... if this was copy-pasted, maybe you missed it... it's supposed to be `express-generator` as a single unit.

---

Make certain that `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` both exists and is in your `PATH` environment variable... If it isn't there, you will have to open a new prompt after adding it.  Some versions of node's installer don't always create or add it correctly.

---

If you are using [[nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)] you will need to ensure that `C:\Program Files\nodejs` is in your path (the installer should work correctly), you'll need to run `nvm` via command prompt `Run as Administrator`.  This is because nvm uses symbolic links from the global install path to a specific version under your profile to run against.

I've been using `nvm for windows` for a few months now (switching from 0.10.x and 0.11.x versions) and it's been a bit easier to work with.

Comment: Hi @Tracker1 this is what i am having in my PATH variable. Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user1>echo &PATH
ECHO is on.
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\windows\system32;C:\wind
ows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Comm
on Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\
TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\user1>

Comment: Is there an express.cmd in `C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm`?  if not.. `npm install -g express` again... also, close and re-open a new command prompt.

Comment: No Sir, I have only node_modules folder in C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm and i ran again npm install -g express, and even now express.cmd is not there.

Comment: i have the npm directory in Roaming folder, do i need to completely delete the node.js and reinstall again.

Comment: It looks like you have a space between `express` and `-generator` as part of your install...

Comment: bingo now the express command is working now, its the space issue btw express and generator. thanks a lot Tracker1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are runing the command promt as System Administrator "This is very important", then do `npm install -g express` after that chang to the directory where you want to create your app and you are good to go. NB if you are using express 4 then install it via `npm install -g express-generator@4`