# error in Install express and express-generator for node.js in windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

well I have a problem when try install this , first I have installed node.js v.7.9.0 . so I create a folder "Test" . In my cmd I enter to this folder and install express with "***npm install express --save***" , this is working, but when install the express-generator with "***npm install express-generator -g***" also working but when write "express testApp"  to generate the structure , the console show error ***"express Is not recognized as a command"*** I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

**express :**

[image]

**info of express-generator install :**

```html
C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\test>npm install express-generator -g
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\express -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin
`-- express-generator@4.15.0
  +-- commander@2.9.0
  | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1
  +-- ejs@2.5.6
  +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
  | `-- minimist@0.0.8
  `-- sorted-object@2.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express is not recognized in cmd in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807420/express-is-not-recognized-in-cmd-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you don't have the installation directory added to your PATH environment variable. For your setup, you want `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin` to be in your PATH. Check your path by running `echo %PATH%` in cmd.

In Windows 10, if you need to add to your PATH, you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) or search for "View advanced system settings" in the start menu, click on "Environment Variables" under the "Advanced" tab, click Path then the "Edit" button, and add a new entry to the PATH that has `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin`.

Comment: The name of the variable should be Path or PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install express globally

```
npm install -g express
```

The way it is installed currently is available only in the folder that you installed it.

If express is not in your PATH you can run it by entering the full path